# Programmatically creating constraints bound to view controller margins

Tags: swift, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to make a view that will act as a sort of "panel", attached to the right side of the view controller.

That is, it is bound to the trailing, top, and bottom margins of the parent view controller, with a static width of 300

However, I just can't seem to get it right, I'm either breaking a constraint or doing something xcode tells me is illegal.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code in the controller

```
    let myView = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.view.addSubview(view)
    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView,
                                           attribute: .Top,
                                           relatedBy: .Equal,
                                           toItem: self.topLayoutGuide,
                                           attribute: .Bottom,
                                           multiplier: 1,
                                           constant: 0)

    let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view,
                                                attribute: .TrailingMargin,
                                                relatedBy: .Equal,
                                                toItem: myView,
                                                attribute: .Trailing,
                                                multiplier: 1,
                                                constant: 0)

    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.bottomLayoutGuide,
                                              attribute: .Top,
                                              relatedBy: .Equal,
                                              toItem: myView,
                                              attribute: .Bottom,
                                              multiplier: 1,
                                              constant: 0)

    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView,
                                             attribute: .Width,
                                             relatedBy: .Equal,
                                             toItem: nil,
                                             attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
                                             multiplier: 1,
                                             constant: 300)

    self.view.addConstraints([trailingConstraint])
    view.addConstraints([topConstraint, bottomConstraint, widthConstraint])
```

Comment: Why don't you use Visual Format Language for this? `"H:[panel(300)]|` and `"V:|[toplayout][panel][botlayout]|"` should be enough.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Actually the problem in your code is that you did not set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` of `myview` to `false`, whenever you want to use auto-layout constraints then you have to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` of a view to false.
Another Problem is that you do not add `myview` on self.view I have updated your code and Its working fine According your constraints.

Put below code in your ViewController .

```
let myView = UIView()
myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
self.view.addSubview(myView)
myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.topLayoutGuide, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.bottomLayoutGuide, attribute:.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 20))

view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute,multiplier: 1, constant: 300))
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: .TrailingMargin, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .TrailingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

Comment: If you want more easy way to add constraints programmatically then you would use https://github.com/keshavvishwkarma/KVConstraintExtensionsMaster.

Comment: Such an old thread, that just saved me so much time.. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

In your example code above, it seems like you are mixing up `view` and `myView` in a few places.  In any event, `widthConstraint` should be added to `myView` and `topConstraint`, `trailingConstraint`, and `bottomConstraint` should be added to `self.view`. The reason for this is constraints must be added to the closest superview ancestor that lays out both views involved in the constraint. In the case where you are constraining a child view attribute to an attribute on its parent view, the constraint must be added to the parent view, since it lays out both itself and the child view. If you have a constraint between two sibling views, the constraint would be added to their parent view, since it is the closest ancestor that lays out both the views involved.

If you're able to target iOS 9.0 and above, it's much cleaner and easier to use the new NSLayoutAnchor and NSLayoutDimension API for creating these kinds of constraints. It also provides strict type checking and the compiler can verify correctness. With these new APIs, your example code would simply become:

```
let myView = UIView()
myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
self.view.addSubview(myView)

let margins = self.view.layoutMarginsGuide
myView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.trailingAnchor).active = true
myView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.topAnchor).active = true
myView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.bottomAnchor).active = true
myView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(300.0).active = true
```

No need to explicitly add the constraints to the right view, etc. You can read more about this method of creating constraints here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutAnchor_ClassReference/

and here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutDimension_ClassReference/

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some ambiguity in your code, you are creating a UIView as myView but adding view to self.view and even constraint also to view itself. So correct your code and replace view with myView.
Secondly setTranslayesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false.
Then add all the constraints to self.view. This should solve your problem.

```
 myView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
 self.view.addConstraints([trailingConstraint, bottomConstraint, widthConstraint])
```

VFL is also a better and clean approach. It actually gives a visualization of how constraint are setup.