# Adding constraints programmatically makes crash

Tags: swift, swift3, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I would like to add programmatically few constraints while I slide from a bottom new table view, but so far I can not understand what am I doing wrong. In my `super view` I have `map view` which have to change `bottom constraint` to make a space for new `tableView` while the button is clicked.

Basically for my table view I need 4 constraints:

- top constraint to the map bottom
- bottom constraint to the tab bar top constraint
- leading and trailing from super view

All the time I am getting crash:

> Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint.

Based on setting constraints from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36509429/5799283)

Here is a code:

```
@IBAction func test(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.mapView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.tabBarController?.tabBar, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        
        view.addConstraints([topConstraint, bottomConstraint, leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint])
//        tableView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.mapView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
//        tableView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.tabBarController?.tabBar, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
//        tableView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
//        tableView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.mapBottomConstaint.constant = 200
            self.centerButtonBottomConstaint.constant = 208
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
```

Comment: why are you providing frame of table view? I think it is not required.

Comment: @PremaJanoti You are right, they are not!

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: Nope. The same stuff.

Comment: Try replacing `self.tabBarController?.tabBar` with `self.bottomLayoutGuide`

Comment: @redent84 Thank you ! That solved my problem, could you say why is that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to set a constraint to a view that is outside your view hierarchy. Auto Layout system provides layout guides to help you align your views with navigation bars and tab bars.

In your bottom constraint, replace `self.tabBarController?.tabBar` with [`bottomLayoutGuide`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621504-bottomlayoutguide).

As a side note, new layout syntax (available on iOS 9+) makes much easier creating programmatic constraints without third party libraries:

```
let topConstraint = tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mapView.bottomAnchor)
let bottomConstraint = tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
let leadingConstraint = tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor)
let trailingConstraint = tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
```

More info for creating programmatic constraints [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html).